# How to get WooCommerce order details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

In WooCommerce from the following line code:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
```

How can I get WooCommerce order details from the order id?

Comment: Why -1? 

i have tried all sorts of solutions.

even tried this one . $order = new WC_Order(159); 

you got any solution then tell me?

Comment: Where did you put that code? What was the output that suggested to you there was a problem? What were you expecting the output to be? Where is `$order_id` coming from in your example? More context is required for users to help you.

Comment: The minus 1 is because it's a low-effort question. As such, it's vague. I agree with Nathan, a lot more context is required here.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec 

I wanted to get shipping method selected at the time of order. so i did not find in the array that you printed.

I got this by 

`$order = new \WC_Order($order_id);
     $ship_method = $order->get_shipping_methods();
     foreach($ship_method  as $SHPM) {
      $wooorder['_selected_shipping_method'] = $SHPM['name'];
     }`


so inserted the method name in array and got the desired result.

Your help is appreciated !

Comment: While the accepted answer is of high quality (however overreaching), I wonder why the actual question was not flagged for being too vague and of low-effort?

Answer (score 404, accepted):

**WOOCOMMERCE ORDERS IN VERSION 3.0+**

Since WooCommerce mega major Update 3.0+ things have changed quite a lot:

- For [**`WC_Order`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.4/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php) Object, properties can't be accessed directly anymore as before and will throw some errors.
- New [**`WC_Order`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.4/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php) and [**`WC_Abstract_Order`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.4/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php) getter and setter methods are now required on the `WC_Order` object instance.
- Also, there are some New classes for Order items:

  - [**`WC_Order_Item`** class](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.4/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order-item.php),
  - [**`WC_Order_Item_Product`** class](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.4/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order-item-product.php),
  - [*`WC_Order_Item_Tax` class*](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.4/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order-item-tax.php),
  - [*`WC_Order_Item_Shipping` class*](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.4/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order-item-shipping.php),
  - [*`WC_Order_Item_Coupon` class*](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.4/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order-item-coupon.php),
  - [*`WC_Order_Item_Fee` class*](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.4/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order-item-fee.php).
- Additionally, [`WC_Data`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.4/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-data.php) Abstract  class allow to access Order and order items data using `get_data()`, `get_meta_data()` and `get_meta()` methods.

> Related: 
> • [How can I get customer details from an order in WooCommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843504/how-to-get-customer-details-from-order-in-woocommerce/57562904#57562904) 
> • [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

So the Order items properties will not be accessible as before in a **`foreach`** loop and you will have to use [these specific getter and setter methods](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.4/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order-item-product.php) instead.

Using [CRUD methods](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/docs/data-management/crud-objects.md) is now mandatory with [High-Performance Order Storage (HPOS)](https://woo.com/document/high-performance-order-storage/)

Using some **`WC_Order`** and **`WC_Abstract_Order`** methods (example):

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object (same as before)
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$order_id  = $order->get_id(); // Get the order ID
$parent_id = $order->get_parent_id(); // Get the parent order ID (for subscriptions…)

$user_id   = $order->get_user_id(); // Get the costumer ID
$user      = $order->get_user(); // Get the WP_User object

$order_status  = $order->get_status(); // Get the order status (see the conditional method has_status() below)
$currency      = $order->get_currency(); // Get the currency used  
$payment_method = $order->get_payment_method(); // Get the payment method ID
$payment_title = $order->get_payment_method_title(); // Get the payment method title
$date_created  = $order->get_date_created(); // Get date created (WC_DateTime object)
$date_modified = $order->get_date_modified(); // Get date modified (WC_DateTime object)

$order_received_url = $order->get_checkout_order_received_url();

$billing_country = $order->get_billing_country(); // Customer billing country

// ... and so on ...
```

> For order status as a conditional method *(where "the_targeted_status" need to be defined and replaced by an order status to target a specific order status)*:
>
> ```
> if ( $order->has_status('completed') ) {
>     // Do something
> }
> ```

Get and access to the order data properties (in an array of values):

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data

$order_id = $order_data['id'];
$order_parent_id = $order_data['parent_id'];
$order_status = $order_data['status'];
$order_currency = $order_data['currency'];
$order_version = $order_data['version'];
$order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];
$order_payment_method_title = $order_data['payment_method_title'];
$order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];
$order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];

## Creation and modified WC_DateTime Object date string ##

// Using a formated date ( with php date() function as method)
$order_date_created = $order_data['date_created']->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$order_date_modified = $order_data['date_modified']->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Using a timestamp ( with php getTimestamp() function as method)
$order_timestamp_created = $order_data['date_created']->getTimestamp();
$order_timestamp_modified = $order_data['date_modified']->getTimestamp();

$order_discount_total = $order_data['discount_total'];
$order_discount_tax = $order_data['discount_tax'];
$order_shipping_total = $order_data['shipping_total'];
$order_shipping_tax = $order_data['shipping_tax'];
$order_total = $order_data['total'];
$order_total_tax = $order_data['total_tax'];
$order_customer_id = $order_data['customer_id']; // ... and so on

## BILLING INFORMATION:

$order_billing_first_name = $order_data['billing']['first_name'];
$order_billing_last_name = $order_data['billing']['last_name'];
$order_billing_company = $order_data['billing']['company'];
$order_billing_address_1 = $order_data['billing']['address_1'];
$order_billing_address_2 = $order_data['billing']['address_2'];
$order_billing_city = $order_data['billing']['city'];
$order_billing_state = $order_data['billing']['state'];
$order_billing_postcode = $order_data['billing']['postcode'];
$order_billing_country = $order_data['billing']['country'];
$order_billing_email = $order_data['billing']['email'];
$order_billing_phone = $order_data['billing']['phone'];

## SHIPPING INFORMATION:

$order_shipping_first_name = $order_data['shipping']['first_name'];
$order_shipping_last_name = $order_data['shipping']['last_name'];
$order_shipping_company = $order_data['shipping']['company'];
$order_shipping_address_1 = $order_data['shipping']['address_1'];
$order_shipping_address_2 = $order_data['shipping']['address_2'];
$order_shipping_city = $order_data['shipping']['city'];
$order_shipping_state = $order_data['shipping']['state'];
$order_shipping_postcode = $order_data['shipping']['postcode'];
$order_shipping_country = $order_data['shipping']['country'];
```

Get the order items and access the data with **`WC_Order_Item_Product`** and **`WC_Order_Item`** methods:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

// Iterating through each WC_Order_Item_Product objects
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ):

    ## Using WC_Order_Item methods ##

    // Item ID is directly accessible from the $item_key in the foreach loop or
    $item_id = $item->get_id();

    ## Using WC_Order_Item_Product methods ##

    $product      = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object

    $product_id   = $item->get_product_id(); // the Product id
    $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id(); // the Variation id

    $item_type    = $item->get_type(); // Type of the order item ("line_item")

    $item_name    = $item->get_name(); // Name of the product
    $quantity     = $item->get_quantity();  
    $tax_class    = $item->get_tax_class();
    $line_subtotal     = $item->get_subtotal(); // Line subtotal (non discounted)
    $line_subtotal_tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax(); // Line subtotal tax (non discounted)
    $line_total        = $item->get_total(); // Line total (discounted)
    $line_total_tax    = $item->get_total_tax(); // Line total tax (discounted)

    ## Access Order Items data properties (in an array of values) ##
    $item_data    = $item->get_data();

    $product_name = $item_data['name'];
    $product_id   = $item_data['product_id'];
    $variation_id = $item_data['variation_id'];
    $quantity     = $item_data['quantity'];
    $tax_class    = $item_data['tax_class'];
    $line_subtotal     = $item_data['subtotal'];
    $line_subtotal_tax = $item_data['subtotal_tax'];
    $line_total        = $item_data['total'];
    $line_total_tax    = $item_data['total_tax'];

    // Get data from The WC_product object using methods (examples)
    $product        = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object

    $product_type   = $product->get_type();
    $product_sku    = $product->get_sku();
    $product_price  = $product->get_price();
    $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();

endforeach;
```

> So using **`get_data()`** method allow us to access to the protected data (associative array mode) …

Answer (score 65):

> **ONLY FOR WOOCOMMERCE VERSIONS 2.5.x AND 2.6.x**
>
> ***For WOOCOMMERCE VERSION 3.0+ see [THIS UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)***

Here is a custom function I have made, to make the things clear for you, related to get the data of an order ID. You will see all the different RAW outputs you can get and how to get the data you need…

Using **`print_r()`** function *(or **`var_dump()`** function too)* allow to output the raw data of an object or an array.

> So first I output this data to show the object or the array hierarchy. Then I use different syntax depending on the type of that variable (string, array or object) to output the specific data needed.
>
> **IMPORTANT:** With **`$order` object** you can use most of [**`WC_order`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html) or [**`WC_Abstract_Order`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#methods) **methods** (using the object syntax)…

---

Here is the code:

```
function get_order_details($order_id){

    // 1) Get the Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // OUTPUT
    echo '<h3>RAW OUTPUT OF THE ORDER OBJECT: </h3>';
    print_r($order);
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '<h3>THE ORDER OBJECT (Using the object syntax notation):</h3>';
    echo '$order->order_type: ' . $order->order_type . '<br>';
    echo '$order->id: ' . $order->id . '<br>';
    echo '<h4>THE POST OBJECT:</h4>';
    echo '$order->post->ID: ' . $order->post->ID . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->post_author: ' . $order->post->post_author . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->post_date: ' . $order->post->post_date . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->post_date_gmt: ' . $order->post->post_date_gmt . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->post_content: ' . $order->post->post_content . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->post_title: ' . $order->post->post_title . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->post_excerpt: ' . $order->post->post_excerpt . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->post_status: ' . $order->post->post_status . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->comment_status: ' . $order->post->comment_status . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->ping_status: ' . $order->post->ping_status . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->post_password: ' . $order->post->post_password . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->post_name: ' . $order->post->post_name . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->to_ping: ' . $order->post->to_ping . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->pinged: ' . $order->post->pinged . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->post_modified: ' . $order->post->post_modified . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->post_modified_gtm: ' . $order->post->post_modified_gtm . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->post_content_filtered: ' . $order->post->post_content_filtered . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->post_parent: ' . $order->post->post_parent . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->guid: ' . $order->post->guid . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->menu_order: ' . $order->post->menu_order . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->post_type: ' . $order->post->post_type . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->post_mime_type: ' . $order->post->post_mime_type . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->comment_count: ' . $order->post->comment_count . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post->filter: ' . $order->post->filter . '<br>';
    echo '<h4>THE ORDER OBJECT (again):</h4>';
    echo '$order->order_date: ' . $order->order_date . '<br>';
    echo '$order->modified_date: ' . $order->modified_date . '<br>';
    echo '$order->customer_message: ' . $order->customer_message . '<br>';
    echo '$order->customer_note: ' . $order->customer_note . '<br>';
    echo '$order->post_status: ' . $order->post_status . '<br>';
    echo '$order->prices_include_tax: ' . $order->prices_include_tax . '<br>';
    echo '$order->tax_display_cart: ' . $order->tax_display_cart . '<br>';
    echo '$order->display_totals_ex_tax: ' . $order->display_totals_ex_tax . '<br>';
    echo '$order->display_cart_ex_tax: ' . $order->display_cart_ex_tax . '<br>';
    echo '$order->formatted_billing_address->protected: ' . $order->formatted_billing_address->protected . '<br>';
    echo '$order->formatted_shipping_address->protected: ' . $order->formatted_shipping_address->protected . '<br><br>';
    echo '- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - <br><br>';

    // 2) Get the Order meta data
    $order_meta = get_post_meta($order_id);

    echo '<h3>RAW OUTPUT OF THE ORDER META DATA (ARRAY): </h3>';
    print_r($order_meta);
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '<h3>THE ORDER META DATA (Using the array syntax notation):</h3>';
    echo '$order_meta[_order_key][0]: ' . $order_meta[_order_key][0] . '<br>';
    echo '$order_meta[_order_currency][0]: ' . $order_meta[_order_currency][0] . '<br>';
    echo '$order_meta[_prices_include_tax][0]: ' . $order_meta[_prices_include_tax][0] . '<br>';
    echo '$order_meta[_customer_user][0]: ' . $order_meta[_customer_user][0] . '<br>';
    echo '$order_meta[_billing_first_name][0]: ' . $order_meta[_billing_first_name][0] . '<br><br>';
    echo 'And so on ……… <br><br>';
    echo '- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - <br><br>';

    // 3) Get the order items
    $items = $order->get_items();

    echo '<h3>RAW OUTPUT OF THE ORDER ITEMS DATA (ARRAY): </h3>';

    foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item_data ) {

        echo '<h4>RAW OUTPUT OF THE ORDER ITEM NUMBER: '. $item_id .'): </h4>';
        print_r($item_data);
        echo '<br><br>';
        echo 'Item ID: ' . $item_id. '<br>';
        echo '$item_data["product_id"] <i>(product ID)</i>: ' . $item_data['product_id'] . '<br>';
        echo '$item_data["name"] <i>(product Name)</i>: ' . $item_data['name'] . '<br>';

        // Using get_item_meta() method
        echo 'Item quantity <i>(product quantity)</i>: ' . $order->get_item_meta($item_id, '_qty', true) . '<br><br>';
        echo 'Item line total <i>(product quantity)</i>: ' . $order->get_item_meta($item_id, '_line_total', true) . '<br><br>';
        echo 'And so on ……… <br><br>';
        echo '- - - - - - - - - - - - - <br><br>';
    }
    echo '- - - - - - E N D - - - - - <br><br>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**Usage (if your order ID is 159 for example):**

```
get_order_details(159);
```

**This code is tested and works.**

> Updated code on November 21, 2016

Answer (score 18):

Accessing direct properties and related are explained

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
            $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
            $order_data = array(
                    'order_id' => $order->get_id(),
                    'order_number' => $order->get_order_number(),
                    'order_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(get_post($order->get_id())->post_date)),
                    'status' => $order->get_status(),
                    'shipping_total' => $order->get_total_shipping(),
                    'shipping_tax_total' => wc_format_decimal($order->get_shipping_tax(), 2),
                    'fee_total' => wc_format_decimal($fee_total, 2),
                    'fee_tax_total' => wc_format_decimal($fee_tax_total, 2),
                    'tax_total' => wc_format_decimal($order->get_total_tax(), 2),
                    'cart_discount' => (defined('WC_VERSION') && (WC_VERSION >= 2.3)) ? wc_format_decimal($order->get_total_discount(), 2) : wc_format_decimal($order->get_cart_discount(), 2),
                    'order_discount' => (defined('WC_VERSION') && (WC_VERSION >= 2.3)) ? wc_format_decimal($order->get_total_discount(), 2) : wc_format_decimal($order->get_order_discount(), 2),
                    'discount_total' => wc_format_decimal($order->get_total_discount(), 2),
                    'order_total' => wc_format_decimal($order->get_total(), 2),
                    'order_currency' => $order->get_currency(),
                    'payment_method' => $order->get_payment_method(),
                    'shipping_method' => $order->get_shipping_method(),
                    'customer_id' => $order->get_user_id(),
                    'customer_user' => $order->get_user_id(),
                    'customer_email' => ($a = get_userdata($order->get_user_id() )) ? $a->user_email : '',
                    'billing_first_name' => $order->get_billing_first_name(),
                    'billing_last_name' => $order->get_billing_last_name(),
                    'billing_company' => $order->get_billing_company(),
                    'billing_email' => $order->get_billing_email(),
                    'billing_phone' => $order->get_billing_phone(),
                    'billing_address_1' => $order->get_billing_address_1(),
                    'billing_address_2' => $order->get_billing_address_2(),
                    'billing_postcode' => $order->get_billing_postcode(),
                    'billing_city' => $order->get_billing_city(),
                    'billing_state' => $order->get_billing_state(),
                    'billing_country' => $order->get_billing_country(),
                    'shipping_first_name' => $order->get_shipping_first_name(),
                    'shipping_last_name' => $order->get_shipping_last_name(),
                    'shipping_company' => $order->get_shipping_company(),
                    'shipping_address_1' => $order->get_shipping_address_1(),
                    'shipping_address_2' => $order->get_shipping_address_2(),
                    'shipping_postcode' => $order->get_shipping_postcode(),
                    'shipping_city' => $order->get_shipping_city(),
                    'shipping_state' => $order->get_shipping_state(),
                    'shipping_country' => $order->get_shipping_country(),
                    'customer_note' => $order->get_customer_note(),
                    'download_permissions' => $order->is_download_permitted() ? $order->is_download_permitted() : 0,
            );
```

Additional details

```
  $line_items_shipping = $order->get_items('shipping');
            foreach ($line_items_shipping as $item_id => $item) {
                if (is_object($item)) {
                    if ($meta_data = $item->get_formatted_meta_data('')) :
                        foreach ($meta_data as $meta_id => $meta) :
                            if (in_array($meta->key, $line_items_shipping)) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            // html entity decode is not working preoperly
                            $shipping_items[] = implode('|', array('item:' . wp_kses_post($meta->display_key), 'value:' . str_replace('&times;', 'X', strip_tags($meta->display_value))));
                        endforeach;
                    endif;
                }
            }

            //get fee and total
            $fee_total = 0;
            $fee_tax_total = 0;

            foreach ($order->get_fees() as $fee_id => $fee) {

                $fee_items[] = implode('|', array(
                        'name:' .  html_entity_decode($fee['name'], ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
                        'total:' . wc_format_decimal($fee['line_total'], 2),
                        'tax:' . wc_format_decimal($fee['line_tax'], 2),
                ));

                $fee_total += $fee['line_total'];
                $fee_tax_total += $fee['line_tax'];
            }

            // get tax items
            foreach ($order->get_tax_totals() as $tax_code => $tax) {            
                $tax_items[] = implode('|', array(
                    'rate_id:'.$tax->id,
                    'code:' . $tax_code,
                    'total:' . wc_format_decimal($tax->amount, 2),
                    'label:'.$tax->label,                
                    'tax_rate_compound:'.$tax->is_compound,
                ));
            }

            // add coupons
            foreach ($order->get_items('coupon') as $_ => $coupon_item) {

                $coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon_item['name']);

                $coupon_post = get_post((WC()->version < '2.7.0') ? $coupon->id : $coupon->get_id());
                $discount_amount = !empty($coupon_item['discount_amount']) ? $coupon_item['discount_amount'] : 0;
                $coupon_items[] = implode('|', array(
                        'code:' . $coupon_item['name'],
                        'description:' . ( is_object($coupon_post) ? $coupon_post->post_excerpt : '' ),
                        'amount:' . wc_format_decimal($discount_amount, 2),
                ));
            }

            foreach ($order->get_refunds() as $refunded_items){
                $refund_items[] = implode('|', array(
                    'amount:' . $refunded_items->get_amount(),
            'reason:' . $refunded_items->get_reason(),
                    'date:'. date('Y-m-d H-i-s',strtotime((WC()->version < '2.7.0') ? $refunded_items->date_created : $refunded_items->get_date_created())),
                ));
            }
```

Comment: Thank You @mujuonly your `order_date` is correct and worked, but standard `get_date_created()` does not worke for me!

Answer (score 7):

You can get all details by order object.

```
   // Get $order object from order ID
      
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
      
    // Now you have access to (see above)...
      
    if ( $order ) {
       // Get Order ID and Key
    $order->get_id();
    $order->get_order_key();
     
    // Get Order Totals $0.00
    $order->get_formatted_order_total();
    $order->get_cart_tax();
    $order->get_currency();
    $order->get_discount_tax();
    $order->get_discount_to_display();
    $order->get_discount_total();
    $order->get_fees();
    $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal();
    $order->get_shipping_tax();
    $order->get_shipping_total();
    $order->get_subtotal();
    $order->get_subtotal_to_display();
    $order->get_tax_location();
    $order->get_tax_totals();
    $order->get_taxes();
    $order->get_total();
    $order->get_total_discount();
    $order->get_total_tax();
    $order->get_total_refunded();
    $order->get_total_tax_refunded();
    $order->get_total_shipping_refunded();
    $order->get_item_count_refunded();
    $order->get_total_qty_refunded();
    $order->get_qty_refunded_for_item();
    $order->get_total_refunded_for_item();
    $order->get_tax_refunded_for_item();
    $order->get_total_tax_refunded_by_rate_id();
    $order->get_remaining_refund_amount();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using wp/wc rest api :

```
        $request = new WP_REST_Request('GET', '/wc/v3/orders/<YOUR_ORDER_ID');

        $response = rest_do_request($request);
        $server = rest_get_server();
        $order = $server->response_to_data($response, false);
        
        print_r( $order['id'] );
        print_r( $order['date_created'] );
        print_r( $order['status'] );
        ...
```

sources: https://wpscholar.com/blog/internal-wp-rest-api-calls/ , https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts

Answer (score -1):

To get WooCommerce order details from the order ID using the following line of code:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
```

You can use the following steps:

1. Get the order object using the **WC_Order()** constructor.
2. Use the getter methods on the order object to get the order details that you need.

For example, to get the order total, you can use the following code:

```
$order_total = $order->get_total();
```

To get the order status, you can use the following code:

```
$order_status = $order->get_status();
```

To get the order billing address, you can use the following code:

```
$order_billing_address = $order->get_billing_address();
```

To get the order shipping address, you can use the following code:

```
$order_shipping_address = $order->get_shipping_address();
```

You can also use the **get_data()** method to get an array of all of the order data. This can be useful if you need to get all of the order details at once.

For example, to get an array of all of the order data, you can use the following code:

```
$order_data = $order->get_data();
```

Once you have the order data, you can use it however you need. For example, you can display it on your website, save it to a database, or send it to a payment gateway.

Answer (score -8):

```
$order = new WC_Order(get_query_var('order-received'));
```

Comment: No explanation?